# dictionary keys to replace strings in pandas dataframe column with dictionary values and perform evaluate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['3 a, 3 ab, 1 b',
                            '4 a, 4 ab, 1 b, 1 d',
                            np.nan] })
```

and a dictionary

```
di = {'a': 10.0,
 'ab': 2.0,
    'b': 1.5,
    'd': 1.0,
    np.nan: 0.0}
```

Using values from the dictionary, I want to evaluate the dataframe rows like this:

3*10.0 + 3*2.0 + 1*1.5 giving me a final output that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['3 a, 3 ab, 1 b',
                            '4 a, 4 ab, 1 b, 1 d',
                            'np.nan'], 'result': [37.5,
                            50.5,
                            0]  })
```

So, far I could only replace ',' by '+'

```
df['col1'].str.replace(',',' +').str.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is on way seem over kill

```
df['col1'].str.split(', ',expand=True).replace({' ':'*','np.nan':'0'},regex=True).\
     stack().apply(lambda x : eval(x,di)).sum(level=0)
Out[884]: 
0    37.5
1    50.5
2     0.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

#### comprehension

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def m(x): return di.get(x, x)

df.assign(result=[
    sum(
        reduce(mul, map(float, map(m, s.split())))
        for s in row.split(', ')
    ) for row in df.col1
])

                  col1  result
0       3 a, 3 ab, 1 b    37.5
1  4 a, 4 ab, 1 b, 1 d    50.5
2               np.nan     0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. We first `explode` your string to rows seperated by a comma, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) function.
2. Then we [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the values by a whitespace (`' '`) to seperate columns.
3. Finally we [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your dictionary to the letters and do a `groupby.sum`:

```
new  = explode_str(df.dropna(), 'col1', ',')['col1'].str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True).append(df[df['col1'].isna()])

s = new[1].map(di) * pd.to_numeric(new[0])

df['result'] = s.groupby(s.index).sum()
```

**Output**

```
                  col1  result
0       3 a, 3 ab, 1 b    37.5
1  4 a, 4 ab, 1 b, 1 d    50.5
2                  NaN     0.0
```

---

Function used from linked answer:

```
def explode_str(df, col, sep):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.count(sep) + 1)
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: sep.join(s).split(sep)})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can insert the keys from your dictionary:

```
for key in di.keys():
    df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(key, '*' + str(di[key]))
```

Then you can insert the operators:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(',', '+')
```

And then you evaluate:

```
df['result'] = df['col1'].apply(eval)
```

Please note that this might do something funny with the `np.nan` because there is an `a` inside that is picked up by the dictionary. There you might want to create some other rules beforehand like:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('np.nan', '0')
```

Comment: this assumes no overlap of the string characters of dictionary keys but two of my dictionary keys are 'a' and 'ab'.

Answer (score 0):

Start from defining a function replacing a source string with
a corresponding value from *di* (will be applied soon):

```
def repl(src):
    return di[src] if src in di else 0.0
```

Then create an auxiliary DataFrame:

- Extract all pairs of regex groups:

  - *n1* - a sequence of digits,
  - *n2* - a sequence of letters or dots (to match also *np.nan*).
- Change *n1* column to numeric.
- Apply *repl* function to *n2*, to replace e.g. *'a'* (a string) with *10.0*
  (a number).

The code is:

```
df2 = df.col1.str.extractall(r'(?P<n1>\d+)? ?(?P<n2>[a-z.]+)').fillna('0')
df2.n1 = pd.to_numeric(df2.n1)
df2.n2 = df2.n2.apply(repl)
```

and it gives the following result:

```
         n1    n2
  match          
0 0       3  10.0
  1       3   2.0
  2       1   1.5
1 0       4  10.0
  1       4   2.0
  2       1   1.5
  3       1   1.0
2 0       0   0.0
```

And to get the sum of products, for each group, run:

```
df2.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda gr: gr.product(axis=1).sum())
```

The result is:

```
0    37.5
1    50.5
2     0.0
```